# Using 'start with' on a set of values

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-query

I'm *very* rusty on my SQL, and I have to work on a query that looks something like the following:

```
select * from (
-- whole bunch of code here
where
-- more bits and pieces
connect by prior x = y
start with z = 'VALUE'
```

I want to run this query on a whole set of values, resulting from using another select statement. I'm looking for something with similar semantics to:

```
start with z in (select * from ...)
```

I'm using an Oracle SQL databse here. There are so many varieties of SQL I find it hard to get something useful from a search, I wouldn't have thought the solution is all that complicated (?). The final query does not have to be necessarily efficient, it will be run only once.

Comment: why don't you use "start with z in (select x from ...)" ?

Comment: I mean why are you trying to find something similar, if IN (subquery) should work fine with START WITH

Comment: I agree, we can use a subquery to feed the START WITH clause

Comment: Oh wow, I thought that was invalid syntax - I just made that syntax up. The syntax error I was getting yesterday was evidently unrelated. No mystery here after all. Doh.

Comment: See the solution proposed by Tom Kyte : https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2755089600346724749